# Django Rest Framework - GenericViewSet with Authentication/Permission decorator

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework, permissions, django-generic-views

Currently i have a simple rest setup for a single entity,

you can create an object and you can retrieve it by the id.

"POST" requires authentication/permission, "RETRIEVE" requires no authentication/permission.

settings.py (requires global authentication/permission from every resource):

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'api.authentication.token_authentication.TokenAuthentication'
    ],
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated'
    ]
}
```

In my resource the global authentication/permission settings are applied correctly but i want to generate an exception for the retrieve method:

my-resource.py:

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from rest_framework import mixins, serializers, viewsets
from rest_framework.decorators import authentication_classes, permission_classes

from api.models import Entity


class EntitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Entity
        fields = [...]
        read_only_fields = [...]


class EntityViewSet(
    mixins.CreateModelMixin,
    mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
    viewsets.GenericViewSet
):

    queryset = Entity.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EntitySerializer

    @permission_classes([]) # this is ignored ?
    @authentication_classes([]) # this is ignored too ?
    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Result:

1. "POST" works as expected
2. "RETRIEVE" return 403 ???

Why does the retrieve method still require authentication and returns 403?

Is there any easier way to accomplish this?

Greetings and thanks!

Answer (score 11):

**Option 1.**

Change the decorator to a class attribute and simply set the permission_classes to `IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly`.
`IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly` will allow authenticated users to perform any request. Requests for unauthorised users will only be permitted if the request method is one of the "safe" methods; GET, HEAD or OPTIONS.

```
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly

class EntityViewSet(
    mixins.CreateModelMixin,
    mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
    viewsets.GenericViewSet
):

    queryset = Entity.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EntitySerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)
```

**Option 2.**

Create your own `permission` and tailor it to your needs. Then, set it as a class attribute.

Example `permissions.py`:

```
from rest_framework.permissions import BasePermission

class IsStaff(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return request.user.is_authenticated and request.user.is_staff
```

Your file:

```
from .permissions import IsStaff
class EntityViewSet(
    mixins.CreateModelMixin,
    mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
    viewsets.GenericViewSet
):

    queryset = Entity.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EntitySerializer
    permission_classes = (IsStaff,)
```

**Option 3.**

Override the `get_permissions` method in your class.

```
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny

def get_permissions(self):
    if self.action == 'retrieve':
        return [AllowAny]
    return [IsAuthenticated]
```

**Option 4.**

If you don't specify any permissions for the `retrieve` method, Django Rest Framework is gonna apply the default one that you have specified in your `settings.py`, which in this case is `IsAuthenticated`. What you should do is, for the `retrieve` method, allow any user.

```
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny

@permission_classes([AllowAny])
def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return super().retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Note that when you set new permission classes through class attribute or decorators you're telling the view to ignore the default list set over the `settings.py` file.

Don't worry too much about the `authentication_classes`, since the `AllowAny` permission class will allow unrestricted access, regardless of if the request was authenticated or unauthenticated.

Comment: Nice and thorough, liked the option 3.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using ***Class Based DRF Views***, use, override **`get_permissions`** method to set the permission properly,
for example,

```
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny, IsAdminUser, IsAuthenticated


class MyViewSet(...):
    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.action == 'retrieve':
            retrieve_permission_list = [AllowAny, IsAdminUser, ]
            return [permission() for permission in retrieve_permission_list]
        elif self.action == 'create':
            create_permission_list = [IsAuthenticated, IsAdminUser]
            return [permission() for permission in create_permission_list]
        else:
            return super().get_permissions()
```

**In your case,**

```
class EntityViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin, mixins.RetrieveModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    ...

    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.action == 'retrieve':
            return []
        else:
            return super().get_permissions()
```

Answer (score 2):

The permission checks are actually done in the `check_permissions` method, which calls each of the defined permissions retrieved via the `get_permissions` method.

So the simplest and easiest would be to override `check_permissions` and add your permission logic there based on the action that is requested (based on method-action map). Add the following to your `EntityViewSet` class:

```
def check_permissions(self, request):
    if self.action == 'retrieve':
        return
    super().check_permissions(request)
```

So no permission check when `action` is `retrieve`, otherwise do as usual.

FWIW, `check_permissions` is actually defined in `views.APIView` (superclass of `generics.GenericAPIView`).

---

**Why your `authentication_classes`/`permission_classes` decorators are ignored?**

The `authentication_classes`/`permission_classes` decorators are designed for function based views e.g. created by the `api_view` decorator.

The `permission_classes` decorator sets `permission_classes` attribute on the decorated function:

```
def permission_classes(permission_classes):
    def decorator(func):
        func.permission_classes = permission_classes
        return func
    return decorator
```

In your case, that's the `retrieve` method but you need to set the attribute on the (to be created) instance or on the class (`EntityViewSet`). As a result the permissions from your `permission_classes` 
decorator on the `retrieve` method does not have any impact. `authentication_classes` decorator also works the same way so that didn't work either.

FWIW, `api_view` actually creates a subclass of `views.APIView` class *dynamically* and sets the `permission_classes`, `authentication_classes` attributes to the subclass from the decorated function <sup>1</sup>. So in that case, it makes sense for the decorated classes to use the `authentication_classes`/`permission_classes` decorators as those attributes will eventually be applied as-is.

<sup>1</sup> The default setting is used if the decorated function does not have the attribute e.g. the relevant decorator was not applied.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is to change the default permission class in the settings file

```python
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'api.authentication.token_authentication.TokenAuthentication'
    ],
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly'
    ]
}
```

Now you don't have to apply permission class on the views. This will be applied by default.

Comment: these are global permissions and therefore a potential security risk. You should always deny access to resources and overwrite these global configurations in your views