# Can not switch from assigning permission_classes to use decorator @permission_classes

Tags: python, django

The below is an api that required authen. It works

```
class some_random_api(generics.GenericAPIView): 
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )
    def get(self,request):
        return HttpResponse("Called successfully")
```

However, I dont like declaring variable. After looking up this document, https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/ . I find an alternative way by using decorator. So I change my code into this.

```
from rest_framework.decorators import permission_classes
class some_random_api(generics.GenericAPIView): 
    @permission_classes(IsAuthenticated)
    def get(self,request):
        return HttpResponse("You call random test api")
```

Now this API does not check Authen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The decorator `@permission_classes` is only applicable to function-based API views as [documented](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#api-policy-decorators).

> REST framework provides a set of additional decorators which can be added to your views. These must come **after** (below) **the @api_view decorator.**
>
> The available decorators are:
>
> ```
> ...
> @permission_classes(...)
> ...
> ```

Also [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#setting-the-permission-policy):

> Or, if you're using the `@api_view` decorator with **function based views**.
>
> ```
> @api_view(['GET'])
> @permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
> def example_view(request, format=None):
>     ...
> ```

An alternative to defining a fixed list `permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )` is to override the `get_permissions()` and assign different permissions for the different HTTP methods as described [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#introspecting-viewset-actions).

```
class some_random_api(generics.GenericAPIView): 
    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.request.method == "GET":  # If using viewsets, the self.action can be used e.g. <if self.action == "retrieve":>
            permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
        else:
            permission_classes = [permissions.IsAdminUser]
        return [permission() for permission in permission_classes]

    def get(self, request):
        return HttpResponse("You call random test api")
```

Related questions:

- [Django Rest Framework - GenericViewSet with Authentication/Permission decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58904662/django-rest-framework-genericviewset-with-authentication-permission-decorator)
- [Django REST Framework - Separate permissions per methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19773869/django-rest-framework-separate-permissions-per-methods)